# How to read several files and write the content into a single file in Tex?

Tags: latex, tex

I have a task whose first step is to read several separate files and reorganize the content into a new single file in Tex. I tried with the following commands:

```
\newwrite\myfile
\immediate\openout\myfile=10solutions.tex 
\def\temp{\Input{inputFile}}
\let\newtxt\temp
\temp
\newtxt
\immediate\write\myfile{\newtxt}
\immediate\closeout\myfile
```

I can see the output of \temp and \newtxt is correct. However when I try to write into "myfile", it reports the following error:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\reserved@a ->\def \reserved@a 
                               *{\@vspacer }\reserved@a 
l.60 \immediate\write\myfile{\newtxt}

If you really absolutely need more capacity,
you can ask a wizard to enlarge me.


Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 14143 strings out of 492902
 197654 string characters out of 3140037
 354467 words of memory out of 3000000
 17607 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 109263 words of font info for 149 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 5000i,18n,77p,3236b,486s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

It looks like an infinitely recursion but I don't know where it results from. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?